# is there a date function in php where i can define a new date variable? like the function Date() in javascript

Tags: php, date

i was wondering if i can define a date using a function in php like in java script. for example in java script it goes something like that:-

```
var sDate = new Date(year, month, day, hour, 0,0,0);
```

is there an equivalent way in php?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's DateTime objects:

Example: $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: nice to see OOP for it never tried that before can you get the timestamps out of that?

Comment: Hey. Once you have the object initialize (i.e., $date = new DateTime('2014-11-28 04:10:00)), you can call the getTimestamp() function ($date->getTimestamp()).

Comment: thanks that was not in the DOCS that were linked to.

Comment: Sorry, there are a lot of pages covering the DateTime class:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Date, time and strtotime

`time();` will return the time in seconds http://php.net/time

`date("str")` will formate current time into string http://php.net/date

`date("str", $time)` will format given time into string http://php.net/date

`strtotime("01/01/1970 00:00:00")` will turn given string to time in E.G `0` http://php.net/strtotime

If your unclear give me what your wanting to do in javascript code and i will update to show it in php

Comment: These are dated methods for handling dates and times and they will not give you the flexibility of the DateTime object. Coming from JS, another language with a functional date object, you'll likely want the control you get with PHP's DateTime object. Please see other answer.

Comment: Yeah but as i asked in the answer about it can you get it as a timestamp? if not Databasing with it is not supported very well oh and another note... Object more memory that int so if you can use an int you should OOP is for code reuse i hate that php are trying to make everything OOP is bigger to load it's bigger to use... Procedural is nice and small.

Comment: You can get the timestamp from a DateTime object quite easily. Example: $date = new DateTime(); echo $date->getTimestamp();

Comment: thanks that was not in the DOCS that were linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
    date("l", mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year,is_dst));

Example:

```
$time = date("l", mktime(0,0,0,10,3,1975));
echo $time;
```

This will output: Oct 3, 1975;
Explaining: mktime returns unix timestamp for the specified date and the date function formats it it be readable for people in the desired format.
For all the formats see the documentation: [php manual date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)